# Wine and mime type association backup and restore

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, backup, wine, mime-types

I'm going to replace Ubuntu with Arch Linux on my laptop and I want to reformat it.
But I want to save ma wine prefixes as I have installed some windows programs that I need.
I have gzipped my `.wine*` folders but I also want to save `mime type associations` (i.e. when I click on a `.docx` file in gnome shell I want it to be opened with MS Word via wine as currently happens in my Ubuntu box).

I discovered that `~/.local/share/applications` folder seems to contain the "magic" `.desktop` files for that.

So, is it enough to backup and then restore that `folder + the .wine*` folders on a new Linux installation to have my file associations back again?

Comment: Do you have different partition for your home and root directories ?

Comment: unfortunately not at the moment but this is what I plan to do when I will install Arch Linux so for the future I'll be safe